# Word choice among "quarrel" "fight" "argument" to describe a medium argument between couples

Tags: word-choice

In this scenario for exmaple: the girlfriend found that the boyfriend onced complained about her with his friends. She was very angry and they had a argument for a few sentences(the argument was not so big nor so small) .
My quesiotn is which word describes their argument best, there are three words in my mind, they are  "quarrel" "fight" "argument". Is one of them good or there are other words that fit better? Can any friend help me with this?

Comment: _Fight_ literally means that they physically attacked one another, though it can be used metaphorically. (NB It's **an** argument.)

Comment: @KateBunting - my son, when a teenager, was watching an American film in which a child said 'I hate it when Mommy and Daddy fight', and he said, 'What, do they duke it out?'.

Comment: How about calling it a **tiff** or a **spat** ? The definition of tiff in Merriam Webster (a petty quarrel) https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tiff contains many possible synonyms.